# Can't get non-members of a group in many-to-many

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two tables; one for groups, another for members.  A third table is an intersection table for members of groups, but we don't see that table when we use the entity framework.  I want to use C# and LINQ to get all the members that are not in a particular group.  I want to list these members so the user can select additional members for the group.  I can't find an example of syntax to make this work.  I am new to C# and LINQ, but well versed in SQL and VB.  Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: Do you have a navigation property in your EDMX?

Comment: Yes.  My EDMX shows my two tables and a relationship between them.  Each table shows one navigational property for the opposite table (named as the plural of the table name).

Comment: You could use lazy loading, or use includes on your query

Comment: I don't know what either of those suggestions is.  Can you please explain?

Comment: {
  var q =
  from p in CadPositions
  join g in CadPosGroups on p equals g.CadPositions into positions
   from g in positions.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new { p.CadPosition1, e.Description, CADPosGroupID = 0 };
}  This doesn't work - complains aout the join being incorrect (using LINQPad4).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use C# and LINQ to get all the members that are not in a
>   particular group.

```
var members = context.Members
    .Where(m => !m.Groups.Any(g => g.GroupId == particularGroupId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  LINQPad complains that 'context' dos not exist.

Comment: @TomM.: `context` is an instance of your derived `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`) class, maybe it has another name in your example. Somewhere you must have such a context to run queries through Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks.  This give me something to research.  Google is my only resource, unfortunately.  I don't know web programming, but trying to learn MVC, EF, LINQ all at once on my own.

Comment: @TomM.: In LINQPad (at least in my version 4.42) you must select the context in your DLL or EXE in the "Database" combobox above the query window. If you have selected it, omit the part `var members = context.` in my query above, just start with `Members....`.

Comment: Database combo box specifies my EF entity.  Removing 'var' from your suggested query still results in 'context' does not exist error.

Comment: var positions = context.CadPositions     
   .Where(m => !m.CadPosGroups.Any(g => g.Id == 4))     
   .ToList();

Comment: I misunderstood.  Trying   CadPositions     
   .Where(m => !m.CadPosGroups.Any(g => g.Id == 4))     
   .ToList();  generates three errors. 1) Delegate 'System.Func<CADAdministration.Models.CadPosition,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments 2) Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type 3) 'CADAdministration.Models.CadPosGroup' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'CADAdministration.Models.CadPosGroup' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: To clarify, CadPositions are the 'members', CadPosGroups are the 'groups'.

Comment: @TomM.: I can't say what's wrong, for me it works in LINQPad. Can you run any query at all, something simple like `CadPositions.Where(m => m.Id == 1)`? If even that doesn't work, try to read something about how to setup LINQPad for Entity Framework or ask a new question here about the setup.

Comment: I can't get any query to run today.  Was working fine a week ago.  I've been fighting this one query for several weeks, but I can't get any syntax to run.  Thanks for your help.